# React on link click load data into right panel

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having an issue trying to visualize or even think about how to abstract this into components.

What I'm trying to do is on my main page I make an API call to load data (objects not in an array) and display them on the left panel.  This part works fine and the data loads correctly.

The issue I am having is trying to load all data associated with the link I click on into the right panel.

I am only displaying the name right now on the left panel and not the rest of the data.  I need to somehow display all data in the object associated with the link I click.

My home js

```
import React from 'react';
import ContactContainer from '../components/contacts';
import ContactDetails from '../views/contact-details';


class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.data) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <ContactContainer />
        <ContactDetails />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

The right panel that should show the object data from link clicked

```
import React from 'react';


class ContactDetails extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.data) {
      return null;
    }

    console.log(this.props)

    return (
      <div>Weeeee</div>
    );
  }
}

export default ContactDetails;
```

My main component that loads the data

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import SearchFilter from '../components/search';


class Contact extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    console.log(this.props.items)
  }

  render() {
    var content;
    var self = this;
    if (this.props.items.length > 0) {
      var items = this.props.items.map(function(item) {
        return (
          <div className="list-item" key={item.person_id}>
            <h5 className="event-title">
              <a href="#" onClick={self.handleClick.bind(self, item.person_id)}>{item.name}</a>
            </h5>
          </div>
        )
      });

      content = {items}
    } else {
      content = <p>No items matching this filter</p>;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {content}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class ContactContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      nameFilter: ''
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadEvents('./javascript/api/people.json');
  }

  loadEvents(url) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({
          data: data
        });
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err, data) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }

  inputFilterUpdate(filterValue) {
    this.setState({
      nameFilter: filterValue
    });
  }

  _hasData() {
    var displayedItems = this.state.data.filter(function(person) {
      var contactName = person.name.toLowerCase(),
          contactNameFilter = this.state.nameFilter.toLowerCase();

      return contactName.indexOf(contactNameFilter) > -1;
    }.bind(this));

    return (
      <div className="contact-list">
        <div className="contact-list__search">
          <SearchFilter updateFilter={this.inputFilterUpdate.bind(this)} />
        </div>
        <div className="contact-list__view">
          <Contact items={displayedItems} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.data) {
      return (
        <div>
          {this._hasData()}
        </div>
      )          
    } else {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return false
  }
}

export default ContactContainer;
```

[image: This image is what I am trying to accomplish]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how your code renders two sections. Looks like just the list of items.

Comment: It shouldn't render the right panel until the person clicks the link on the left panel and then it should render the right panel with the data in the object.  That is the part I'm having trouble with, trying to figure out how to attach the object with the id that matches the link in `Contact` to render in a new part.  I have edited the source to show where I currently am.  The current issue is that the link returns all objects and not the one associated with the link id

Comment: This is a master-detail view. React router has an [example master-detail contact app](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/0.13.x/examples/master-detail/app.js) :-)

Comment: Ok thanks!  I'll take a look and see what I can figure out.  I did have the right panel view and updated original code to show it in case it is helpful.